# How to run javascript scripts from within VS Code using F5 or CTRL + F5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, visual-studio-code, vscodium

When I try to run any javascript file from VS Code using native VS Code options: either 'Start debugging (F5)' or 'Run without debugging (CTRL + F5)', I get the following error:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module '/home/altair/Documents/Desktop/test/hello_world.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Where `/home/altair/Documents/Desktop/test/hello_world.js` is the path to file that I am trying to run.

I can run JS scripts fine from the terminal (including the terminal opened inside VS Code) with `node ./hello_world.js`, so the problem must be somewhere in VS Code.

Is it possible to run JS scripts from within VS Code using F5 or CTRL + F5?

Comment: Yes, there are actually some run configurations, but an easier way is to use Code Runner extension from marketplace to start right away

Comment: can you share the content of hello_world.js?

Comment: Sure, here is the content: 1: // console.log('Hello World!')
2: process.stdout.write('Hello World!') The content is not the problem though, as I said I can run this file fine from the terminal - it prints 'Hello World!'.